# Setting the same host address on different networks

Tags: subnet, lan, ip-address

I have a set of devices to be deployed on different local networks which have to be configured without DHCP.

Every network has the same subnet mask and the gateway and the device in every network have always the same host portion of the address (e.g. XXX.XXX.XXX.9 for the gateway and XXX.XXX.XXX.11 for the device).

Is it possible to write a single `/etc/network/interfaces` file without knowing the network portion of the address so that the device will configure a static IP for itself with host portion XXX.XXX.XXX.11 and gateway XXX.XXX.XXX.9?

Comment: Questions about host configuration are off topic here. Since you seem to be talking about Linux or UNIX, you can consider asking this question on https://unix.stackexchange.com

Comment: Ok, I apologise for the mistake, thank you for pointing me to the right community :)